# keep columns of type factor using approx on a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, resampling, factors, approximation

I have a big dataframe with a lot of columns. Some of them are of type double and others are of the type factor. I resample the dataframe by adding a new column "time" with the approx function and the method = "constant". After that all factor columns are changed to doubles.

For example:

```
So my idea looks like this:

time = seq(1, 6, by = 0.1)

df1 <- data.frame(ecuTime = c(2, 4, 6), a = as.factor(c("male", "female", 
                                                   "male")), b = c(1, 3, 5))

df2 <- data.frame(ecuTime = c(1, 3.2, 3.4, 6), c = as.factor(c("car", "car", 
                                                    "bike", "car")), d = c(2, 3, 5, 6))

dfComb <- merge(df1, df2, by = "ecuTime", all = TRUE)

approxData <- cbind.data.frame(time, sapply(dfComb[, names(dfComb)], 
                                        function(y, x, nout) 
                                        approx(x, y, nout, method = "constant", na.rm = FALSE)$y,
                                        x = dfComb$ecuTime, nout = time))
```

Is it possible to keep the factor columns as factors and the columns of type double as doubles even if I use the function approx?

Edit: 
I found out that it doesn't make sense to use the approx function on factors and don't want to use na.rm = TRUE because I have a lot of NA's in some columns and if I replace them with previous values there will be a really big difference to the original data regarding the distributions etc. Is there an alternative Solution to just do the approx function for non factor columns and then merge it with the original factor columns? I think it makes sense to not fill up the factor columns with prior values and only use the original values connected with the resampled time like 0.1, 0.2 etc. After that it could be merged.

I am just confused how to combine df1 and df2 with a resampled time frequency so my distributions and line plots are completely different to the original data. My final goal I want to achieve is to make some comparison of some specific factors in a specific time frame. So I can't compare different variables because another one might be NA.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the factor columns? Do you want them just to be skipped in the creation of `approxData`? (Also, in your example, the first row of `approxData` is `NA`, except for the `time` variable. Was that intended?)

Comment: yes it is intended to be NA's.I don't want the factor columns to be skipped. They are treated right (filling up with prior values) but they shall not be converted to doubles (binary data in this case). They shall fill up as a factor like (NA, "male", "male", "female", "female", "male") and NOT as doubles like (NA, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2). I don't want to change all the double columns with specific labels again to factors afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not clear on the big picture of what you're trying to get done here, which is fine; I understand the specific question well enough. However, I'm trusting that you're *really, really sure* this is a good idea -- at face value, I'd be pretty worried about doing something resembling arithmetic via the `approx()` function on the underlying integers of a factor variable (which are totally meaningless). It seems to me like there is probably a "better" (i.e. less hacky) way to get this done, but I'm not in a position to help you do that since your overall goals aren't clear to me.

That said, here's one possible road map to do what you want using `base` R:

- identify which variables should be factors
- inside `approxData`, convert those variables back into factor type
- remap the `levels` of the new factor variables based on the corresponding values from `df`

Code, expanded with an extra factor column (to verify that it runs properly in the case with more than one factor variable):

```
time = 1:6
df <- data.frame(ecuTime = c(2, 4, 6), a = as.factor(c("male", "female", 
                                                       "male")), b = c(1, 3, 5),
                 c = c("blue", "blue", "yellow"))
str(df)

approxData <- cbind.data.frame(time, sapply(df[, names(df)], 
                                            function(y, x, nout) 
                                              approx(x, y, nout, method = "constant")$y,
                                            x = df$ecuTime, nout = time))
str(approxData)

factor_vars <- names(df[, sapply(df, is.factor)])
approxData[, factor_vars] <- 
  lapply(factor_vars, function(x) {
    approxData[[x]] <- factor(approxData[[x]]); 
    levels(approxData[[x]]) <- levels(df[[x]]); 
    approxData[[x]]
  })

str(approxData)
```

---

For the edited question: here's some code to produce a new data frame, `dfComb_resample`. This data frame has an expanded `ecuTime` variable, values for `a, b, c, d` copied from `df1` and `df2` where appropriate, and `NA` values everywhere else. (If I missed the mark on what you wanted, let me know.)

```
time = seq(1, 6, by = 0.1)

df1 <- data.frame(ecuTime = c(2, 4, 6), a = as.factor(c("male", "female", 
                                                        "male")), b = c(1, 3, 5))

df2 <- data.frame(ecuTime = c(1, 3.2, 3.4, 6), c = as.factor(c("car", "car", 
                                                               "bike", "car")), d = c(2, 3, 5, 6))

dfComb_resample <- 
  Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x=x, y=y, by = "ecuTime", all = TRUE),
         list(data.frame(ecuTime = time), df1, df2))
```

How it works: `Reduce()` is a shortcut to merge three (or more) data frames at a time in this context. Note that you'd get some unexpected behavior if any of the merged data frames had variables in common, which they don't in this example.

Comment: this solutions works great. but you are right. I found out that it doesn't make sense to use the approx function on factors. Is there an alternative Solution to just do the approx for non factor columns and then merge it with the original factor columns? The factor columns need to be resampled too, but I think it makes sense if will not fill up with prior values and only use the original values connected with the resampled time like 0.1, 0.2 etc. After that it could be merged.

Comment: That's definitely doable, but can you explain for me what those columns are supposed to look like? Is it always just supposed to be: an `NA` entry, followed by the first entry repeated twice, followed by the second entry repeated twice, etc until the final entry is posted just once? I still don't know what larger task you're trying to accomplish. (Also, you refer to "resampling" a few times, but as far as I can tell nothing is really being sampled - or at least, certainly not `sample()`d. I'm guessing it's just a gap in my knowledge.)

Comment: I changed the description of the question ;)

Comment: Please forgive me, but even with the updated description I still have no idea what you're trying to do. At a very basic level: if an original factor variable is (for instance) `c("blue", "blue", "yellow")`, then what *should* the new vector look like? By what algorithm should it be created? (If you just want to use your existing approach on only the numeric data, that's easy -- but then I don't know you'd combine the factors back in, because `approxData` and `df` have different numbers of rows.)

Comment: The place where I'm most confused is the use of the word "resampled" -- I only understand that to mean something to do with a random sample, which seems pretty clearly not to be happening here. I'm sure it's a gap in my own understanding, but that's where I'm currently stuck (I think).

Comment: With resampling i mean to make a new time series, In this case from 1 to 6 and with a frequency of 10Hz (by = 0.1). I dont know the perfect way how the dataframes should be combined ;) by all the new observations are created the you get a lot of new NAs and so you cant filter for something like “car” because there are only corresponding NAs in the other variables. And if you fill up too much NAs in the variables you add something that isnt there so your distributions are completely wrong.

Comment: OK -- I now understand conceptually what you're trying to do, but I don't have a clear sense of *how* you want to do it; there are many ways to do such a thing that require various choices along the way, and there is no magic function that will do it automatically for you. Since my suggestion of NA -> first entry x2 -> ... didn't seem to satisfy you, I'd be happy to help if you can edit your post with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I think it is best to do it step by step. How do I create a df with the new timeline like 0.1, 0.2 etc. and then only sort the original values to this new timeline WITHOUT adding any values but the orignal ones and the rest is filled up with NAs? It doesn't matter if these are factor or numerics etc. I just want to have a equidistant time series with the original values.